# Firebase Android Authenticated User

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am pretty new to Firebase and have a question.

I'm looking to link my new authenticated user to a database that I have working.

I have class named addChild which contains an editText for add children's name, and need this to be linked to the authenticated user on a database. So when that user logs in, they can see their children's names that they have inputted.

Does anybody know how I could do this? I have set up the real-time database connection Im just not sure where to go from here.

Thanks
This is how I created user.

```
 auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
     .addOnCompleteListener(CreateUserAccount.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateUserAccount.this, "User Account Created" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateUserAccount.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(CreateUserAccount.this, LandingPage.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: After you complete creating new user inside run another query and save data to database.

Comment: What you are doing is wrong. You want to add the children of a user in an activity and then you want that user to create his account, how does that work? Who is adding the children name ? the admin?

Comment: @PeterHaddad no you misunderstood, I, a user, have created an account. I can sign in, I am now an authenticated user. There is another form where I can add the names of my children. I want these names to be stored in a database where I can retrieve them later.

Comment: @user12345 check the edit then

Answer (score 1):

After you authenticate a user using Firebase Authentication, then also you can send his `uid` to the database:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String useruid=user.getUid();
```

then in the database you would have this:

```
Users
  useruid
     name: userx
     email: userx@gmail.com
```

---

```
String name = editText.getText().toString();
String email = editTxt.getText().toString();

DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(useruid);
ref.child("name").setValue(name);
ref.child("email").setValue(email);
```

Edit:

```
  } else {
 FirebaseUser user= task.getResult().getUser();
 DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());
ref.child("name").setValue(name);
ref.child("email").setValue(email);
        startActivity(new Intent(CreateUserAccount.this, LandingPage.class));
         finish();
        }
```

to add the children in the other activity:

1. First retrieve the names from an edittext

then add them like this:

```
Children
   useruid <--- the id that is in the usernode above
       childname: john
   useruid
       childname: james bond
```

Comment: `child("Users").child(useruid);`

Comment: Sorry I am still confused - where do I put FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String useruid=user.getUid();

Comment: Hi thank you peter, however the add children name is actually from a different java class

Comment: But I need to store this value? The user must be able to store their children's name once they input them in the add_children form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166570/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-user12345).

Comment: hi, I am able to retrieve names from an edittext, my problem is getting the uid that is in the usernode abovee

Comment: thats how you get it `FirebaseUser user= task.getResult().getUser(); String useruid=user.getUid();`

Comment: And do i put that in createuser? or addchild?

Comment: in both, inside createuser, you create this `Users
  useruid
     name: userx
     email: userx@gmail.com` then inside addchild you create this `Children
   useruid <--- the id that is in the usernode above
       childname: john
   useruid
       childname: james bond` so in both.

Comment: in createuser after the else{ add it `FirebaseUser user= task.getResult().getUser(); String useruid=user.getUid();` in addchild, add it like this `FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String useruid=user.getUid();`

Comment: It is saying variable useruid is never used even though I have declared it.

Comment: in createuseraccount just add what is wrote after the `else` like this `FirebaseUser user= task.getResult().getUser();
 DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());` add the id in the child

Comment: Got it what do u mean add the id in the child

Comment: getuid() gives you the id of the user, just meant to add it like this `child(user.getUid())`

Comment: UID still coming up different